# Tetris rotation without using arrays

Tags: optimization

I am making a Tetris clone. Is there any way that I can avoid using a 2D array for storing a Tetris block?

**EDIT**: Suppose I have an array to store an L-shaped piece:

```
1 0
1 0
1 1
```

But for the sake of rotation, I do that shape as this:

```
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0
```

I can do this in either objects or arrays. If I use objects then create four objects for each "square", and I can store the position of each square, and rotate it about the piece's center. But I am finding a better way to optimally perform a rotation on the piece. I believe rotating this array 90 degrees would take O(n^2) time. I try to avoid making rotated copies, and instead rotated on the fly. What algorithm or approach should I use?

Comment: You should use whatever's easiest. This doesn't seem like it's worth optimizing, unless the profiler tells you you're spending a lot of time there. O(n^2) hardly matters when n is 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you really really really wants to you can store the data as a 1D array with each 2 pairs means an block's x and y position. Like so [-2,0,-1,0,1,0,2,0] with (0,0) being the implicit center of rotation. You can improve on this further by not using array of ints but pack your data into the smallest bits possible.